# How to fix do/while loop to re-run the program?

Tags: c++, do-while

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void getAges(double ages[]);
char getChoice();
void displayInOrder(double ages[]);
void displayInReverse(double ages[]);

int main()
{
    double ages[5];
    char choice;
    do
    {
        getAges(ages);
        char choice = getChoice();
   
        if (choice == 'R')
        {
            displayInReverse(ages);
        }
        else if (choice == 'O')
        {
            displayInOrder(ages);
        } 
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid Entry - Must be O or R!" << endl;
        }

        // I am having trouble right here on getting the program to re-run the entire ask number process.
        // the computer does not read the do-while function at all and just exits the code.
        // If possible, I would like help on figuring out where I am supposed to place do-while
        // in order to get the program to re-ask the entire output at the bottom. 

        cout << "Run program again? (Y/N)?  ";
        cin >> choice;
    }
    while (choice == 'Y');

    // I am also getting a "Variable 'choice' is uninitialized when used here" error
    // for the while (choice == 'Y'). I am completely lost on how to fix this.

    return 0;
}

char getChoice()
{
    char choice;
    cout << "How do you want to see the ages displayed?\n";
    cout << "Enter O for In Order, or R for In Reverse (R): ";
    cin >> choice;
    choice = toupper(choice);
    cout << endl;
    return choice;
}

void getAges(double ages[])
{
    cout << "Enter five ages: \n";
    for(int num = 0; num < 5; num++)
    {
        cin >> ages[num];
    }
}

void displayInOrder(double ages[])
{
    cout << "Here are the ages in order: \n\n";
    for (int num = 0 ; num < 5; num++ )
    {
        cout << ages[num] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

void displayInReverse(double ages[])
{
    cout << "Here are the ages in reverse: \n\n";
    for (int num = 4 ; num >= 0; num-- )
    {
        cout << ages[num] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

Output

```
Enter five ages: 
1
2
3
4
5
How do you want to see the ages displayed?
Enter O for In Order, or R for In Reverse (R): R

Here are the ages in reverse: 

5  4  3  2  1  

Run program again? (Y/N)?  Y
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

It does not re-run program again.

Comment: Your `do/while` loop is declaring its own `choice` variable that *shadows* the `choice` variable declared by `main()` outside of the loop. Get rid of the variable inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void getAges(double ages[]);
char getChoice();
void displayInOrder(double ages[]);
void displayInReverse(double ages[]);

int main()
{
    double ages[5];
    char choice='N';
    do
    {
        getAges(ages);
        choice = getChoice();

        if (choice == 'R')
        {
            displayInReverse(ages);
        }
        else if (choice == 'O')
        {
            displayInOrder(ages);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid Entry - Must be O or R!" << endl;
        }



        cout << "Run program again? (Y/N)?  ";
        cin >> choice;
    }     while (choice == 'Y');



    return 0;
}

char getChoice()
{
    char choice;
    cout << "How do you want to see the ages displayed?\n";
    cout << "Enter O for In Order, or R for In Reverse (R): ";
    cin >> choice;
    choice = toupper(choice);
    cout << endl;
    return choice;
}

void getAges(double ages[])
{
    cout << "Enter five ages: \n";
    for (int num = 0; num < 5; num++)
    {
        cin >> ages[num];
    }
}

void displayInOrder(double ages[])
{
    cout << "Here are the ages in order: \n\n";
    for (int num = 0; num < 5; num++)
    {
        cout << ages[num] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

void displayInReverse(double ages[])
{
    cout << "Here are the ages in reverse: \n\n";
    for (int num = 4; num >= 0; num--)
    {
        cout << ages[num] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

choice is local to do/while in your program,just delete the internal char